# understanding of tense in "there is been"

Tags: sentence-construction, tense

what is the meaning and when do you we use  this "there is been a misunderstanding"

espicially this part "there is been" when do we use this tense and how this is different fron the tense "there was a misunderstanding"

Comment: There *has been* a misunderstanding in that sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the phrase should be:

> There has been a misunderstanding

This usually implies that the misunderstanding has **just happened**, or has just affected events. For example:

> *Person A:* I thought I was meant to bring one box, not two!
>
> *Person B:* There has obviously been a misunderstanding.

The phrase:

> There was a misunderstanding.

implies that the misunderstanding was in the **past**. For example:

> *Person A:* Why did you not bring two boxes yesterday?
>
> *Person B:* There was a misunderstanding.

In practice, the difference is not always that clear cut, but as a rule of thumb it is quite useful:

- 'has been' = 'has **just** been'
- 'was' = 'was **some time ago**'

Answer (score 0):

"There is" and "There has" are both contracted to "There's", and it is very easy for an English language learner to mix them up. "There's/There has" can only be followed by a past-participle verb: "[There's/There has] been a misunderstanding". "There's/There is" can be followed by a number of things, including, in this case, a noun phrase: "[There's/There is] a misunderstanding".